# How to print elasticsearch query using searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

We are using searchkick to query our ES and I want to print the ES query generated by searchkick?

I tried the below code but it gives me an error `` undefined method `searchkick_query' for #<Searchkick::Results:0x000000010633d9c8> ``

```
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
    field :search_products, [Types::ProductType], null: false do
      argument :query, String, required: true
    end

    def search_products(query:)
      # Search for products using Searchkick
      results = Product.search(query)

      # Get the Elasticsearch query generated by Searchkick
      query_json = results.searchkick_query.to_json

      # Log the query to the Rails server console or log
      Rails.logger.info("Searchkick Elasticsearch Query: #{query_json}")

      # Return the search results as an array of ProductType objects
      results.to_a
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this explains how to do it: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#debugging-queries